What is the punishment if an unmarried person commits zina with a married person?
Assalamualaikum, on behalf of one of my friends I am asking the question. She is unmarried ( never ever was married,) and unfortunately has Committed fornication with a married man.Now what will be her punishment to cleanse the sin? As hadith says, If an unmarried woman and an unmarried man commit fornication they will receive 100 lashes and if a married woman and a married man commit fornication they will be lashed 100 time and stonned to death.Here in the case,the woman is unmarried and the man is married, what will be punishment specifically for both of them? As hadith didn’t clearly describe this kind of act be done. ( by an unmarried woman and a married man).  Will the woman also be stonned to death because committing it with a married man? Or she will just receive 100 lashes?

Note that it is permitted to conceal the act and repent. A punishment is only going to be carried out if it is proven to a court. A hadith says: "Avoid these immoral actions that Allah has forbidden. Whoever does any of them, let him conceal that which Allah has concealed, and let him repent to Allah, for whoever tells us what he has done, we will carry out the ruling mentioned in the Book of Allah on him." - https://shamela.ws/book/2266/9021

As for the answer to your question, the woman will get whipped and the man stoned to death. This is evident from the hadith (https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6633) as in it an unmarried person committed zina with a married one and one was whipped and the other stoned.
